# Efficiently creating an array from a filtered sheet

Tags: vba, excel

[edit] I realised why everyone does this with loops; my plan was to use .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Address to return the row(s) of the results of the results of the filter, but that returns a string. Strings have a limit of 256 characters, so with even moderately fragmented data some will be truncated. However, I think this approach is still more efficient than grabbing the table contents row-by-row.

I recently needed to make an array from a filtered sheet. Because the filtered results will be in multiple areas, the code I found online all referred back to the sheet in loops. I believe I have come up with a much more efficient approach, which grabs all the table in one go, then grabs the information relating to the rows that are visible. It does not have to go row-by-row to grab the data, nor does it have to redim the array after its initial size is set.

Some operations could be combined (sacrificing readability for efficiency) but otherwise I think this is a faster and neater way than any I've yet seen.

I am particularly interested in any efficiency improvements, and any vulnerabilities which could/should be dealt with. Thanks in advance!

```
Function ArrayFromFilter(Table As Range) As Variant

    Dim FullData() As Variant, Trimdata() As Variant, FilterZones() As String, Filters() As String, FilterRows() As Long
    Dim numZones As Long, curZone As Long, curRow As Long, curCol As Long, FirstRow As Long
    Dim numItems As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Output As String

    FirstRow = Table.Rows(1).Row - 1 'this an offset used later
    
    'grab the entire unfiltered table - faster to process it in VBA than to cycle through on the sheet
    FullData() = Table
    
    'grab the result row numbers by area
    numZones = Table.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas.Count
    ReDim Filters(1 To numZones)
    For curZone = 1 To numZones
        Filters(curZone) = Table.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(curZone).EntireRow.Address
    Next
    
    ReDim FilterZones(1 To numZones, 1 To 2)
    ReDim FilterRows(1 To numZones, 1 To 2)
    
    'split the zones into start and end rows
    For i = LBound(Filters()) To UBound(Filters())
        'first split each zone into its first and last rows
        FilterZones(i, 1) = Left(Filters(i), InStr(Filters(i), ":") - 1)
        FilterZones(i, 2) = Right(Filters(i), InStr(Filters(i), ":") + 1)
        'now take just the row from each cell and convert to a number, then remove the offset of the start of the data
        FilterRows(i, 1) = (CDbl(Split(FilterZones(i, 1), "$")(1)) - FirstRow)
        FilterRows(i, 2) = (CDbl(Split(FilterZones(i, 2), "$")(1)) - FirstRow)
        'ta-da we have an array with the first and last row of each zone inside the overall filtered data - now work out how many items there are
        numItems = numItems + (FilterRows(i, 2) - FilterRows(i, 1)) + 1
    Next
    
    'go through the table, moving only the useful bits to the trimmed data
    ReDim Trimdata(1 To numItems, 1 To UBound(FullData, 2))

    curRow = 1
    For i = 1 To numZones
        For j = FilterRows(i, 1) To FilterRows(i, 2)
            For curCol = 1 To UBound(FullData, 2)
                Trimdata(curRow, curCol) = FullData(j, curCol)
            Next
            curRow = curRow + 1
        Next
    Next

'uncomment this block for testing to show that the data has been grabbed
'    For i = 1 To UBound(Trimdata(), 1)
'        For j = 1 To UBound(Trimdata(), 2)
'            If j = 1 Then
'                Output = Trimdata(i, j)
'            Else
'                Output = Output & ", " & Trimdata(i, j)
'            End If
'        Next
'        Debug.Print Output
'    Next
    
    ArrayFromFilter = Trimdata

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use of error handlers with SpecialCells:** Using SpecialCells in VBA can potentially throw errors, particularly Error 1004 when no cells of the specified type are found. It's good practice to have error handling in place for these instances. An example implementation might look like this:

> On Error Resume Next
> Set rngSpecial = Table.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
> If Err.Number <> 0 Then
> Err.Clear
> ' Handle error or exit function
> End If
> On Error GoTo 0

**Storing the result of SpecialCells in a variable:** The SpecialCells method is called multiple times in this code. This method can be resource intensive, particularly with larger ranges. Storing the result in a variable and then using that variable would improve efficiency. Example:

> Dim rngSpecial As Range
> Set rngSpecial = Table.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
> Now, you can use rngSpecial instead of calling Table.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) each time.

**Misleading variable name - Trimdata:** The variable name Trimdata can be misleading because in programming contexts, "trim" is often used to refer to removing white spaces from the start and/or end of strings. Here, a more accurate name might be FilteredData or VisibleData to better reflect that this array contains only the visible (i.e., unfiltered) data from the range.

**Simpler calculation of row numbers:** The calculation for the number of rows in a range can be simplified by dividing the total count of cells in the range by the count of columns. This can be done as follows:

> numRows = Table.Count / Table.Columns.Count

Remember that this will give you the total number of rows, including those hidden by filters. If you only want the number of visible rows, you would need to perform this operation on the range returned by SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).

```
' This function accepts a range in Excel (the "Table") as input and returns a filtered array that excludes any hidden or non-visible cells in the range.
Function ArrayFromFilteredRange(Table As Range) As Variant
    ' Declare a Range object to hold the target cells
    Dim Target As Range
    ' In case of any error in the following operations, program execution will resume at the next statement
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Assign to "Target" only the visible cells from "Table"
    Set Target = Table.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    ' Resets the error handling to its default behavior
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' If no visible cells were found, return an empty array and exit the function
    If Target Is Nothing Then
        ArrayFromFilteredRange = Array()
        Debug.Print "ArrayFromFilteredRange:", "Target Is Nothing"
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Declare a variable to hold the number of columns in the target range
    Dim columnCount As Long
    columnCount = Target.Columns.Count

    ' Declare a variable to hold the number of rows in the target range
    Dim rowCount As Long
    rowCount = Target.Count / columnCount
 
    ' Declare an array to hold the data from the target range
    Dim Result As Variant
    ' Set the dimensions of the Result array to match the size of the target range
    ReDim Result(1 To rowCount, 1 To columnCount)

    ' Declare variables to assist in navigating the target range and populating the Result array
    Dim Area As Range
    Dim AreaData As Variant
    Dim c As Long, r As Long, row As Long

    ' Loop through each area of the target range
    For Each Area In Target.Areas
        ' Loop through each row in the current area
        For row = 1 To Area.Rows.Count
            ' Increment the row count for the Result array
            r = r + 1
            ' Extract the values from the current area
            AreaData = Area.Value
            ' Loop through each column in the current area
            For c = 1 To columnCount
                ' Assign the current cell's value to the corresponding element in the Result array
                Result(r, c) = AreaData(row, c)
            Next
        Next
    Next

    ' Return the Result array
    ArrayFromFilteredRange = Result
End Function
```

## Addendum

I overlooked the whole point of the OP's code.  He postulates that it is more efficient to load all the data into a variable and loop over it.  As opposed to iterating over each areas values.

```
' This function calculates the relative row index of an area within a given target range.
' It takes the target range and area index as inputs and returns the relative row index.
Function GetAreaRelativeRowIndex(Target As Range, AreaIndex As Long) As Long

    ' Get the row number of the first cell in the given area within the target range
    ' Subtract the row number of the first cell in the target range to calculate the relative row index
    ' Adding 1 at the end accounts for the 1-based index system in VBA
    GetAreaRelativeRowIndex = Target.Areas(AreaIndex).Row - Target.Row + 1

End Function
' This function accepts a range in Excel (the "Table") as input and returns a filtered array
' that excludes any hidden or non-visible cells in the range.
Function FilteredRangeData(Table As Range) As Variant

    ' Declare a Range object to hold the target cells
    Dim Target As Range
    
    ' On Error Resume Next allows the program to continue with the next line of code 
    ' even if there is an error
    On Error Resume Next
    
    ' Assign to "Target" only the visible cells from "Table"
    ' .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) allows to target only cells that are visible
    Set Target = Table.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    ' Resets the error handling to its default behavior
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' If no visible cells were found or if Table is a single cell, 
    ' return an empty array and exit the function
    If Target Is Nothing Or Table.Count = 1 Then
        Dim EmtpyResult(1 To 1, 1 To 1) ' Define a 1x1 array
        FilteredRangeData = EmtpyResult ' Set function result as the empty array
        Debug.Print "FilteredRangeData:", "Target Is Nothing" ' Output message for debugging
        Exit Function ' Exit the function
    End If

    ' Declare a variable to hold the number of columns in the target range
    Dim columnCount As Long
    columnCount = Target.Columns.Count

    ' Declare a variable to hold the number of rows in the target range
    ' This is calculated by dividing the total count of cells in the target by the column count
    Dim rowCount As Long
    rowCount = Target.Count / columnCount
 
    ' Declare an array to hold the data from the target range
    Dim Result As Variant
    ' Set the dimensions of the Result array to match the size of the target range
    ReDim Result(1 To rowCount, 1 To columnCount)
    
    ' Declare a variable to store all values in the table
    Dim AllValues As Variant
    AllValues = Table.Value
    
    Dim AreaIndex As Long
    Dim AreaRowCount As Long
    Dim AreaRelativeRowIndex As Long
    Dim Count As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    ' Loop through all the areas in the target range
    For AreaIndex = 1 To Target.Areas.Count
        ' Get the relative row index of the current area in the target range
        AreaRelativeRowIndex = GetAreaRelativeRowIndex(Target, AreaIndex)
        ' Get the number of rows in the current area
        AreaRowCount = Target.Areas(AreaIndex).Rows.Count
        ' Loop through all the rows in the current area
        For r = AreaRelativeRowIndex To AreaRelativeRowIndex + AreaRowCount - 1
            ' Increment the count
            Count = Count + 1
            ' Loop through all the columns
            For c = 1 To columnCount
                ' Assign the cell value in AllValues to the corresponding cell in Result
                Result(Count, c) = AllValues(r, c)
            Next c
        Next r
    Next AreaIndex
    
    ' Return the Result array
    FilteredRangeData = Result
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you - I had spotted the specialcells error issue but not the rest; I will work through. I'm inclined to continue the approach of reading the entire table, then using the specialcells data to filter it in memory, as I think that will run faster. I also gather that dimming every variable at the top of the code isn't good practice so will fix that.

Comment: I think your approach to determining the rows in each area is probably a lot smarter than mine - I appear to have been stuck with my idea of parsing the string returned by .address. On reflection my approach is "clever" but might not be efficient.

Comment: @AndiAllan you premise was very clever.  I've seen a lot of the address parsing over the years.

Comment: I did find an issue in your new code - with relatively unfragmented data, it's very slow. Moving the Areadata = Area.value line above the "for row = 1 to area.rows.count" line makes it much faster. I think at present yours is grabbing the entire area for every row it cycles through. With that change your code is very fast for chunky or fragmented tables - really nice.

Comment: @AndiAllan you are right.  What was I thinking. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the comments from @Tinman I have updated and substantially changed my code. I've stuck with my initial idea of storing the entire data set, then storing the row numbers for the visible (ie filtered) data, and processing in memory, because I thought it ought to be quicker with less fragmented data.

Specific changes:

- Moved all variable dim statements to just before the variable is
  first used
- Added error trapping to the specialcells bit in case there are no visible cells
- Stored the specialcells range to a variable
- Renamed the filtered data array to something less misleading
- Used the suggested table.count / table.columns.count approach to
  calculate the number of items
- Fixed an error in the original Filterzones() code that used a Right
  where it should have used a Mid - the original worked by accident
  when a zone started and ended with row numbers with the same number
  of digits

My initial tests with a 5000 line range suggest that my expectation is true; once the data is heavily fragmented my code does take slightly longer, but if the data is in larger contiguous chunks it's significantly quicker. I suppose this makes it an alternative rather than a more efficient approach.

I am most grateful for the feedback - I have now voted for Tinman's answer.

```
Function ArrayFromFilter(Table As Range) As Variant

    Dim RowOffset As Long
    RowOffset = Table.Rows(1).row - 1 'this an offset used later
    
    'grab the entire unfiltered table - potentially faster to process it in VBA than to cycle through on the sheet
    Dim FullData() As Variant
    FullData() = Table
    
    'grab the filtered rows address(s)
    Dim Specials As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Specials = Table.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Specials Is Nothing Then
        ArrayFromFilter = Table
        GoTo MakeOutput
    End If
    
    'grab the result row numbers by area
    Dim numZones As Long
    numZones = Specials.Areas.Count
    
    'now work out how many items there are
    Dim numItems As Long
    numItems = Specials.Count / Specials.Columns.Count
    
    Dim Filters() As String
    ReDim Filters(1 To numZones)
    
    Dim curZone As Long
    For curZone = 1 To numZones
        Filters(curZone) = Specials.Areas(curZone).EntireRow.Address
    Next
    
    Dim FilterZones() As String
    ReDim FilterZones(1 To numZones, 1 To 2)
    ReDim FilterRows(1 To numZones, 1 To 2)
    
    'split the zones into start and end rows
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(Filters()) To UBound(Filters())
        'first split each zone into its first and last rows
        FilterZones(i, 1) = Left(Filters(i), InStr(Filters(i), ":") - 1)
        FilterZones(i, 2) = Mid(Filters(i), InStr(Filters(i), ":") + 1)
        'now take just the row from each cell and convert to a number, then remove the offset of the start of the data
        FilterRows(i, 1) = (CDbl(Split(FilterZones(i, 1), "$")(1)) - RowOffset)
        FilterRows(i, 2) = (CDbl(Split(FilterZones(i, 2), "$")(1)) - RowOffset)
        'ta-da we have an array with the first and last row of each zone inside the overall filtered data
    Next
    
    'go through the table, moving only the useful bits to the trimmed data
    Dim FilteredData() As Variant
    ReDim FilteredData(1 To numItems, 1 To UBound(FullData, 2))

    Dim curRow As Long, j As Long, curCol As Long
    curRow = 1
    For i = 1 To numZones
        For j = FilterRows(i, 1) To FilterRows(i, 2)
            For curCol = 1 To UBound(FullData, 2)
                FilteredData(curRow, curCol) = FullData(j, curCol)
            Next
            curRow = curRow + 1
        Next
    Next
    
    ArrayFromFilter = FilteredData
    
MakeOutput:

'uncomment this block for testing to show that the data has been grabbed
'    Dim Output As String
'    For i = 1 To UBound(FilteredData(), 1)
'        For j = 1 To UBound(FilteredData(), 2)
'            If j = 1 Then
'                Output = FilteredData(i, j)
'            Else
'                Output = Output & ", " & FilteredData(i, j)
'            End If
'        Next
'        Debug.Print Output
'    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! While OPs are [encouraged to answer their own questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) bear in mind that ["_Your answer must meet the standards of a Code Review answer, just like any other answer. **Describe what you changed, and why**._"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). [Code-only answers that don't actually review the code are insufficient](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1463) and are subject to deletion.

Comment: I misunderstood you post.  I updated my answer.